# Custom buttons with swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, uibutton

So, in the screenshot here attached there are 3 big "buttons". When clicking one button there is a small arrow underneath and the content below changes.
I would like to do something like that.

As you can see on each button there are several texts with different size.
I was thinking of using a custom segmented control. Is this the way to do?
Or should I use a custom button and handle the "selected" state for each one of them.

How to do a custom button with different texts inside?

[image]

Comment: WWDC14 session 221 - Creating Custom User Interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is more or less the behavior of a `UITabBar` and `UITabBarController`. However, I don't think the system is set up to let you customize the appearance like that.

The custom control you're describing is also similar to a `UISegmentedControl`, but not quite that either. Again I don't think `UISegmentedControl` is set up for custom behavior like that.

I'd probably create a custom subclass of `UIControl` that has 3 states (or better yet, N states, with text for each state, optional images, etc, with an array of settings for all the possible states, and a delegate that can be notified when the user changes states.)

Then you should probably create a parent view controller that contains the custom control at the top and a view below that hosts one of N child view controllers. When the user taps on one of the segments of your control you'd animate in a different child view controller. You could use the method 
`transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:`, which is pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use `UIPageViewController` as the user is expected to swipe left and write and if one of the buttons is clicked you can simulate the movement of both the content[the `UIViewController`(s) and the page indicator easily

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using a segmented control, unless you want to use an image for the text, since `UISegmentedControl` doesn't support attributed strings. I would use 3 `UIButtons` with attributed strings as the titles, so you can have different font sizes for different lines. The triangle at the bottom can be drawn easily enough using a `CAShapeLayer`. It would be best to subclass `UIButton` so you can put the logic necessary to construct the title with different fonts, and do the drawing outside of your view controller class.

Comment: Nice this solution also.